I've turned it off/I have
A goes into the room where B is sitting. A asks B to turn the air conditioner off because they feel cold, and B fulfills their request. Here's the conversation they have:
A: "It's rather cold in here. Can you turn the air conditioner off, please?"
B: "[I've turned it off]/[I have]."
A: "Thank you."
Can either option be used? Is the short "I have" a natural response in this context? Thanks.

If the A/C was already off because B had turned it off, and so it doesn't need to be turned off, in American English the reply could be:

I already did.  It was freezing in here.

(In AmE, we just don't say "I have done". That's BrE.)
But if the A/C is still on, and B must leave A to go over to the thermostat in order to turn it off, upon returning B can use simple past or present perfect. Both are idiomatic in American English:

I turned it off.
I've turned it off.


If the A/C is still on, and B must leave A to go to the thermostat to turn it off, can B simply say "I did." upon returning, rather than saying "I turned it off."? Thanks in advance.

@prof1589  Idiomatic would be "I just did" where "just" is expressing the sense that the action occurred only seconds or moments ago.  I did doesn't really fit that situation, where B returns from turning it off and informs A of that fact.

"I have" would be just about possible, but a far more natural reply would be "I have done".
However, this would normally be said if B had already turned the air conditioner off before A asked. In response to a request, I think B would simply do it, perhaps saying something like "OK" or "Yes, it is rather cold".

As @TimR remarks, I have done sounds to Americans very British. I myself am wont to use it with my wife, but it’s in a jocular way and between two intimates who are also fairly anglophilic. The pinnacle of human accomplishment is Foyle’s War.

And there's emphasis on have, right?   "I have done".

@PaulTanenbaum  Do you address your wife  as "Mrs Tanenbaum"?  If you do, you've crossed over to the PBS dark side.

No, @TimR, I don’t. But would She Who Must Be Obeyed suffice to get me over that stile?

@PaulTanenbaum  You could have picked that up second hand  hanging out on a vintage woodworking tools forum. Not that you have, but it is inconclusive evidence.

Only "I've turned it off".
You can't answer just "I have", because the question doesn't have this word.
It'd be okay it you had been asked:
A: "Have you turned off the air conditioner?"
B: "I have."

Can B reply "I did" ？

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
